# Cannot find module 'minizlib'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, installation, reactive-programming

I am pretty new to React-Native. I install react-native on my Mac using the code below:

```
npm install react-native -g react-native-cli
```

I got the error:

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm Err! Cannot find module 'minizlib'
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem please?

Comment: Why you won't to run `npm i -g create-react-native-app`?

Comment: Still have the same problems!

Comment: check if it is already installed? use       ' npm -v ' command

Comment: I think this would shed some light on problem: https://github.com/tj/n/issues/453

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem

```
npm i minizlib --global
```

This helped me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
brew install node
brew install watchman
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

Follow the exact steps in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html in the Building Projects with Native Code tab.

Answer (score -2):

New to this myself as a disclaimer but you may want to try uninstalling node.

If you installed node with Homebrew try...

$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node