# Missing module minizlib when creating a project

Tags: reactjs

When I try to create a project with `create-react-native-app Myapp`, I get an error message that says:

```
Error can not find module 'minizlib`.
```

Comment: I think it is the same of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495253/cannot-find-module-minizlib

Comment: Is this one or two questions?

Comment: have you installed `node`?